# boost spirit extracting first word and store it in a vector

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have problems with Boost.Spirit parsing a string.

The string looks like

```
name1 has this and that.\n 
name 2 has this and that.\n 
na me has this and that.\n
```

and I have to extract the names. The text "has this and that" is always the same but the name can consist of spaces therefore I can't use graph_p.

1) How do I parse such a string?

Since the string has several lines of that format I have to store the names in a vector.

I used something like

```
std::string name;
rule<> r = *graph_p[append(name)];
```

for saving one name but

2) what's the best way to save several names in a vector?

Thanks in advance

Konrad

Answer (score 4):

I think this will do the trick:

```
vector<string> names;
string name;
parse(str,
    *(  
       (*(anychar_p - "has this and that.")) [assign_a(name)]
       >> "has this and that.\n") [push_back_a(names, name)]
     ))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the newer Spirit V2.x (which is the default since Boost V1.42), this is as easy as:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

std::vector<std::string> names;
std::string input = "name1 has this and that.\n"
                    "name 2 has this and that.\n"
                    "na me has this and that.\n";
bool result = qi::parse(
    input.begin(), input.end(),
    *(*(qi::char_ - " has this and that.\n") >> " has this and that.\n"),
    names
);
```

After which, if `result` is `true`, the vector `names` will hold all parsed names (tested with Boost V1.45).

Answer (score 0):

I presume there is a reason why you are using [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/spirit/classic/index.html) and not [STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html)'s [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)'s [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find.html) method?  E.g:

```
string s = "na me has this and that.\n";
myVector . push_back( s.substr( 0, s.find( "has this and that" ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "has this and that" use:

```
qi::lit("has this and that")
```